# What is a good practice to make authentification design(login form) for a system

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans, database-schema

Hi guys currently I am making an employee managment system.

I have made some forms of the applications like CRUD form of employee ,and stuff.
I also have implemented the login form , with users from database but I am having a problem to design the database correctly.
I want each time that I add an employee from Employee CRUD form , to be added as a user that can login into the system..
 Currently I am adding users manually in the database, but I dont want this  , because the  users will be from 3 categories , Employee,Admin,And manager..
I am using JPA for database.Below  I will show you a photo of the database schema.

[image: DB SCHEMA]

What will be a good practice so each time I add an employee to be added as a USER that can login into the system,

Thank you for every answer, and for your time..

Comment: The best practice is not to make one, because they're very difficult to write correctly. Using an existing library such as Spring Security is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to have booleans inside your employee table, (isUser, isManager ...). This is good if you can have one or more roles and if you don't need more informations (a user is just an employee with a boolean checked).

--

If you need more informations about your roles, you can link your employee table to an other table with the fields you need.

For exemple between an employee and a user, add a foreign key inside Employee (userID) and a table named user with the fields you need. For example :

userID, password, lastConnectionDate ...

--

An other way would be to have a table "roles" and a table "employe". The idea is to add an other table "employeeRoles" that have 3 keys :

IDEmployeeRoles, IDEmployee, IDRole

Like that you will be able to link many employees with many roles.